# The order of click event handled by parent view and child view

Tags: android, events, click, parent

I have been working on android development for a while, but I am still confused about this question..

From android documentation said, the event will start from root view, and dispatched to the child view.
Which means viewgroup should get touch event before view(which is its child), but from what I have debugged, this is not the case...

I create a RadioGroup, then add three radiobutton into it, every time when I click radiobutton, its click event is triggered. Radiogroup's click event is not even fired...

How can we explain this?

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When a child handles the onClick, the parent does not receive the event.  If you want to see the parent get the event, don't set an onClickListener on the child.

onTouch events are handled a bit differently.

Comment: How are the onTouch events handled? For example if you have some views on top of each other and on the bottom view you handle onTouch but on the top view you don't handle it and you want to inhibit onTouch on the bottom view if the tap is on the top view - is there a way to do so without implementing onTouch?