# Android + When to use onInterceptTouchEvent()?

Tags: android

Sorry if this is vague, but can someone please give me an example of when to use `onInterceptTouchEvent()`?

I understand the concept, intercepting child view touches in the parent `ViewGroup`, but why would I need to do tht?

Example usage might help me to better understand it.

Answer (score 2):

When: handler touch event in parent before the event dispatch to the child.

How: create a class extents from ViewGroup(like LinearLayout ...) class and override the onInterceptTouchEvent(), the you can process something you want in the method.

see: [the-order-of-click-event-handled-by-parent-view-and-child-view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598320/the-order-of-click-event-handled-by-parent-view-and-child-view)